# Unique homomorphism both ways

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups and that there exists a unique homomorphism $f:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ and a unique homomorphism $h:G_2\rightarrow G_1$. Will it be true then that $G_1$ and $G_2$ re isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There's a unique homomorphism from the trivial group to any group and to the trivial group from any group. In fact, any two isomorphic groups of order greater than $2$ have more than one isomorphism between them, because such groups have nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: In fact, because we always have the trivial homomorphism going each way, it follows that there are unique homomorphisms $G_1 \to G_2$ and $G_2 \to G_1$ if and only if $G_1$ has no non-trivial quotients isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2$, and vice-versa.

Examples of this are: 1) $G_1$ and $G_2$ have coprime orders. 2) $G_1$ and $G_2$ are non-isomorphic simple groups.